# Should I use SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android

I am currently using this setup I heard it is not advised to use anymore as support has been discontinued.

```
setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.testlist, cur, 
                displayFields, displayViews
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) the issue is not with using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` it's with the constructor you're using.  Apparently it uses the UI thread for updates which can cause an application to appear sluggish or unresponsive.  Use the constructor that includes the `flags` parameter to avoid getting the deprecation warning.  Alternatively,

> As an alternative, use LoaderManager with a CursorLoader

**Edit**

> Flags used to determine the behavior of the adapter, as per CursorAdapter(Context, Cursor, int).

Comment: what are the flags parameter for?

Comment: @Max, see my edits above.  More info is available at the link I provided

Comment: thanks, I took a look and there only seems to be two flags and one of which is also not adviced. Should I use the other flag or is it better trying the loadermanager approach?

Comment: @Max, to be honest with you, I'm not sure.  That might be worth posing as a separate question on SO.